# How to use objects specified by a manager instead of the default objects in a class based or function view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

My code:

models.py

```
class EmployeeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().exclude(employed=False)

class NotEmployedEmployee(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(employed=False)

class Employee(models.Model):
    objects = EmployeeManager()
    not_employed = NotEmployedEmployees()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    employed = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
class EmployeeListView(ListView):
    model = Employee
    template_name = 'tmng/employee_list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        resultset = EmployeeFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        context['filter'] = resultset
        return context


class EmployeeUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'tmng/employee_update.html'
    model = Employee
    fields = '__all__'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, f'Employee "{self.name}" changed!')
        return '/'
```

For all my currently working employees my list and update view works fine.
But I also want a list/update-view for my not-employed employees so I can 'reactivate' them once they rejoin the company.
For the list view I found a semi-solution by using a function based view.

views.py

```
def not_employed_employee_list_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    template_path = 'tmng/employee_not_employed.html'
    context = {'employees': Employee.not_employed.all()}
    return render(request, template_path, context)
```

So what I'm looking for is a way to see list/update non employed employees. Is there a way to say to class based / functions views to use not the default employees but the 'non_employed' employees?

Comment: You can override `get_queryset` of `ListView` and `UpdateView` to use a certain manager you want depending on some criteria.

Comment: Yes indeed that works, thankyou @bdbd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not create new templates, but just created a new class based list view

```
class EmployeeNotEmployedListView(EmployeeListView, ListView):  

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Employee.not_employed.all()
```

And for the update view, I updated the default Employee update view

```
class EmployeeUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'tmng/employee_update.html'
    model = Employee
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Employee.objects.all() | Employee.not_employed.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, f'Employee "{self.name}" changed!')
        return '/'
```

Comment: Seems you can just inherit your original class and just add `get_queryset`

Comment: yes, indeed, edited my answer to your comment